# syntastic complaining about ES6 module syntax

Tags: javascript, vim, ecmascript-6, syntastic

I love syntastic for javascript but I am using the new [ES6 module tranpiler](https://github.com/square/es6-module-transpiler) and syntastic is not happy about these type of statements:

```
import Typeahead from './lib/components/ember-typeahead';
```

Is there anyway that I can keep syntastic quiet about this type of statement?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

[Syntastic will use JSHint to check JavaScript syntax](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/blob/3.3.0/plugin/syntastic/registry.vim#L39) [if it's available](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/blob/3.3.0/syntax_checkers/javascript/jshint.vim) (which I recommend over jslint).

[JSHint supports es6 syntax with the `esnext` flag](http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/#esnext), which includes support for the `export` and `import` module syntax.

I suggest [adding a `.jshintrc` file](http://www.jshint.com/docs/) to your project to control JSHint's behavior (and thus Syntastic's) for your entire project:

```
{
  "esnext": true
}
```

Note: be careful, since using the `esnext` flag will add support for *all* of [es6's new language sytax](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features) that JSHint currently supports, not just the module syntax.

**Note**: [`esnext`](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#esnext) has now been deprecated in favour of the [`esversion`](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#esversion) syntax.

```
{
  "esversion": 6
}
```

Answer (score 21):

To work around this, I'd suggest the following steps as recommended here: [Configure Vim for React](https://jaxbot.me/articles/setting-up-vim-for-react-js-jsx-02-03-2015):

Install `eslint` and `babel-eslint`:

```
npm install -g eslint babel-eslint
```

Create a local `.eslintrc` config in your project or a global `~/.eslintrc` configuration:

```
{
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "settings": {
        "ecmascript": 6
    },
    "rules": {
        "strict": 0 // you can add more rules if you want
    }
}
```

Finally, configure `syntastic` to use `eslint`:

```
let g:syntastic_javascript_checkers = ['eslint']
```

Comment: umm, all makes sense except for the last one.. where do you put `let g:syntastic_javascript_checkers = ['eslint']` ? sorry, bit of a newb in zed/syntastic

Comment: in your .vimrc file which is normally located `~/.vimrc`. But you can have local .vimrc files too so could be elsewhere.